# What is the difference between get_permalink vs get_the_permalink?

Tags: permalinks

What is the difference between [get_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) vs [get_the_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nothing.

`get_permalink()` is the original function, and is used to get the permalink URL for a post.

`get_the_permalink()` was introduced in 3.9 simply so the permalink function was consistent with the other post-related template tags, such as `get_the_title()`, `get_the_content()`, which are all prefixed with `get_the_`.

The equivalent functions for echoing the result of those functions are the same but without the `get_`, such as `the_title()`, but in the equivalent for `get_permalink()` is not `permalink()`, it's `the_permalink()`, so the lack of `get_the_permalink()` was an inconsistency.

Using the function just calls `get_permalink()`, which still exists for backwards compatibility reasons, so the result will be exactly the same.